# Running Fastlane Gym build in Rosetta

Tags: ios, apple-m1, fastlane, rosetta

We have a new M1 MacMini that we want to use for CI/CD purposes. Our main issue is that we have a really old external dependency that doesn't allow us to build the app for the simulator on ARM architecture. We managed to make it build on this machine by running Xcode in Rosetta mode. So as long as we use Rosetta mode with Xcode we can run the app on the simulator with no issues.

Our problem is that we are using Fastlane gym to build the app in our CI/CD flow, so Xcode doesn't run in our flow. We did a lot of research but didn't manage to find a solution that fits our needs.

The question is: Can Fastlane gym run with Rosetta?

Comment: `Can Fastlane gym run with Rosetta` - yes, but could you describe the problem a little better (post the error here and specify the name of the "old external" dependency )?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: If you set the terminal to run with Rosetta it seems to fix the issue on most machines, but we still have problems on others. I guess a complete reinstall of everything on the machines that don't work should fix the problem, but we didn't manage to do that yet..